# What anime is this blue-tinted image of a layer of skin/paint peeling off the face of a woman from?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell

[image]

What is this image from? I am desperate to find out.

Comment: you could always use this plugin (for google chrome) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-by-image-by-google/dajedkncpodkggklbegccjpmnglmnflm?hl=en

or something else such as TinEye to find out the image source

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did Google Image Search. Maybe this is **Ghost in the shell** (1995).

---

## [Ghost in the Shell - Movie 1995](http://myanimelist.net/anime/43/Ghost_in_the_Shell)

[image: GitS movie poster]

## Synopsis

> In the year 2029, the barriers of our world have been broken down by the net and by cybernetics, but this brings new vulnerability to humans in the form of brain-hacking. When a highly-wanted hacker known as 'The Puppetmaster' begins involving them in politics, Section 9, a group of cybernetically enhanced cops, are called in to investigate and stop the Puppetmaster. The pursuit will call into question what makes a human and what is the Puppetmaster in a world where the distinction between human and machine is increasingly blurry.

Comment: You are awesome buddy.

Answer (score 2):

To be exact, that frame is from the original Ghost in the Shell movie, and depicts the creation of the cyborg body of the Major.  It is part of the opening title sequence - which for being 20 years ago still thrills.